# Unknown error code during application install: "-25"

Tags: google-play-store, installation

I uploaded an app to Google Play Store. But some users reported that they were able to download the app, but unable to install the app. They are getting the error

> Unknown error code during application install: "-25"

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix this error?

Comment: I am getting the same error. did you have any luck in resolving this? what device are you using? (Smasung galaxy S4 in my case). My app is a phonegap app - is this also the case with you?

Answer (score 1):

check to make sure that the `versionCode` of your new version is not lower then the one you have installed already.

For me this was what was causing the  "Installation error code: -25" error on samsung galaxy S3.